# Kentico not reading updated SQL Server servername, username or password

Tags: asp.net, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, kentico

Kentico CMS is hosted as Azure app service. Had to change admin password for our Azure SQL Server. After updating the password in the Kentico root web.config's connection string, Kentico is still complaining with this error message

> SQL Connection Error The application could not connect to the
>   database, please check the connection string in the web.config file
>   and SQL server availability.
>
> Original error: Login failed for user 'myadminusername'

Note that there is no way I can clear Kentico cache because I cannot access the portal at all. And there is no IIS since this is an Azure app service. I have tried restarting the app service several times and no luck.

Strangely changing username or server address in web.config has no change in the error message. The same old username is displayed in the error message.

I have no issues using the connection string values in SSMS or a different application. Both work with new password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 places to change this username and password:

- web.config
- Azure Application settings

By default, the application settings override the web.config settings.  So you can change your password all day long in the web.config and as long as your Azure application settings remain unchanged, your website will never see those updates. I suggest checking in the Azure portal under the applications settings/configuration and see if there is a `CMSConnectionString` in the settings.  If so, update the credentials there.

Comment: Wow life saver...starting working after changing the CMSConnectionString value in Azure app's Application Settings and then restarting the app, and then waiting a few minutes (initially was giving same error message)!

Comment: The change of the settings will trigger the restart and unfortunately, it takes about 5 mins for it to restart.